# How to I use my account in Google Play?

Tags: clash-of-clans

My sister gave me her old phone and I downloaded clash of clans using the account my sister's account in google play. And when I reach th5 I link my clash of clans to google play using my real account and now I have a problem loading my clash of clans to my new phone. This is because whenever I try to play clash of clans it isn't my account anymore, it's my sister's account that is loading. Also, my gmail account is there but the name is my sister's. Google play says welcome "My Sister's Name", but the gmail account is mine. This is because the email under my sister's name is my email. This is what I mean:

> Welcome "My Sister's Name" "My Sister's Email"

So how do I log out of my sister's account and log in to mine?

Comment: @UniKitty Please don't criticise other people's language. English is not an easy language to learn, especially if your native language isn't a related one. Correcting the mistakes in an edit is quite enough. At most, ask for clarifications or confirmation in the comments, if you had to make guesses when making the corrections.

Answer (score 1):

Steps:

1. Go to your Android Menu >> Settings >> Accounts : then add account, Choose Google, You'll asked, Do you want to add an existing account or create a new one?  Select New.

Note: Follow process of creating new Google account.

1. After you created a new account Go To: Menu >> Settings >> Device  Select Applications >> Find and select Clash of Clans apps and then Click Clear Data.
2. Now play Clash of Clans, Sign in your newly made account.

Here how:

Open coc > Settings > disconnect/connect > Log in your Account > Pop up box out > Type CONFIRM >> finish . the game will reload..

having problem: follow details [How to Play multiple accounts on android](http://www.mycoclab.com/2015/06/how-transfer-coc-account.html)